# Probability of normal distribution larger than half normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I am pretty new to normal distribution and stuck on this question:

X ~ N(0, 1)

Y ~ N(0, 1)

X independent of Y

What is the probability of P(X>|2Y|)?

I know linear combination of normal distribution is normal distribution but what about linear combination of normal distribution and absolute value of normal distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view $(X,Y)$ as a random point on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. The joint distribution is the standard bivariate normal distribution and is radially symmetric about the origin.

Plot the region consisting of pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying $x > |2y|$; you will find this is an infinite cone (an infinite slice of pizza or pie, if you will) with vertex at the origin. By the symmetry mentioned above, the probability of the random vector $(X,Y)$ being in this slice is equal to the relative angle of the slice (relative to a full turn, i.e. $2\pi$ radians or $360$ degrees).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why it is an infinite cone... Is there any mathematical way to calculate this probability?

Comment: @ZiyueJin "I don't understand why it is an infinite cone..." Did you plot the region of interest? It might help you understand why it is a cone...

Comment: Should any region fall within 1? Because the variance is 1?

Comment: This explanation really helps me understand what happened but I still want a solution related to integral over PDF.

Comment: "I still want a solution related to integral over PDF" Why? Sorry but this is absurd.

Comment: @ZiyueJin The probability is the integral of the joint density over the region I described in my answer. If you do a change of variables to use polar coordinates then you can probably recover the answer. But this is just extra work to do exactly what I described in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand this approach now.